# Overlapping Images?

Tags: javascript, css, jquery-isotope

Seems like it only happens in all browsers

How do I fix this?

The problem with it is that it doesn't seem to be displaying the problem I'm having.. so I'm not sure what to do about that.. I've tried disabling everything but isotope.. all jquery/css and It still shrinks all the images

Also, If I hit the "All" under filter it stretches the page to how its suppose to look so that could be helpful in figuring this out

my script is below

```js
$(function(margin) {
  var $margin = $("#kehl-grid").isotope({
    itemSelector: ".grid-box-1",
    // Different transition duration
    transitionDuration: "1s"

  });

  // on filter button click
  $(".filter-container li").click(function(e) {
    var $this = $(this);

    // Prevent default behaviour
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.filter li').removeClass('active');
    $this.addClass('active');

    // Get the filter data attribute from the button
    var $filter = $this.attr("data-filter");

    // filter
    $margin.isotope({
      filter: $filter

    });
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/isotope-layout@3/dist/isotope.pkgd.min.js"></script>
<div class="filter-container">
  <ul class="filter">
    <li class="active" data-filter="*">All</li>
    <li data-filter=".Planters">Planters</li>
    <li data-filter=".Mirrors">Mirrors</li>
    <li data-filter=".Rugs">Rugs</li>
  </ul>
</div>


<div id="kehl-grid">
  <!-- Mirrors -->
  <div class="grid-box-1 Mirrors ">
    <a href="product-detail-4.1.1.html">
      <div class="image-mask"></div>
      <img src="img\product\4.1.1-1-cr.jpg" alt="" />
      <h3>KACHINA</h3>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-box-1 Mirrors ">
    <a href="product-detail-4.1.2.html">
      <div class="image-mask"></div>
      <img src="img\product\4.1.2-1-cr.jpg" alt="" />
      <h3>ETHNO</h3>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Still unclear what the problem is? Do you want to have overlapping images or are your images overlapping when they shouldn't?

Comment: Read the documentation: https://isotope.metafizzy.co/layout.html#imagesloaded

Comment: It's same problem, please check the image " https://imgur.com/WXCj4Ko "
when i click on filter all problems will solved like " https://imgur.com/hr3aaz6